# "Provider is not capable of the attempted operation" exception when I want to create COM

Tags: c#, com-port

> This is a sample code for creating COM.
> first Create a new instance of the Win32_PnPEntity WMI class then Create a new instance of the Win32_PnPEntity class. It seems to some things wrong with Win23_PnPEntity.

I run this "wmic /namespace:\root\cimv2 path Win32_PnPEntity get ProviderType /format:list
" and get "Node - DEV-2023
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query"

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\cimv2");

        // Create a new instance of the Win32_SerialPort WMI class
        ManagementClass serialClass = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_SerialPort"), new ObjectGetOptions());

        // Create a new instance of the Win32_SerialPort class
        ManagementObject serial = serialClass.CreateInstance();

        // Set the properties for the new serial port
        serial["DeviceID"] = "COM3"; // Set the COM port number
        serial["Name"] = "My Serial Port"; // Set the name of the port
        serial["Description"] = "This is my serial port"; // Set the description
        serial["Caption"] = "My Serial Port"; // Set the caption
        //serial["ProviderType"] = "RS232"; // Set the provider type

        // Save the new serial port instance
        serial.Put();
```

Comment: Code makes little sense, you can't create a serial port in software.  Hardware required, its driver adds the entry.

Comment: excuse me I mean virtual port

Comment: Then it virtually makes no sense, there's no mechanism to install a virtual port through WMI.  As the exception reminds you.

Comment: is it possible to use a third-party driver or an emulator? Is this completely impossible?

Comment: @Hamed What are you actually trying to accomplish here? What (real-world or business/domain) problem are you trying to solve? Why do you feel you need a virtual Serial/COM port (and where/how is this virtual port going to respond to data passed into it?).

Comment: I need to create a pair of virtual com to simulate a connection to a real COM. This is for handling multiple connection to device (printer ).

Comment: @Hamed Please explain how you think "virtual" COM ports can help you here...

Comment: I'm in the middle of R&D about this. After creating 2 virtual port, I think I can give one to those who want to use the device and connect the other one to real COM .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search about this, it seems, creating a virtual serial port requires kernel-level support, usually in the form of a driver. As such, this cannot be done in C#.

Comment: I used this https://github.com/paulakg4/com0com
works fine